# Integrating stripe connect into react native app for marketplace

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, react-native-ios

Are there any docs/examples on how to integrate stripe connect into react native? I would like to collect payments and then payout in my react native app, just like a marketplace. I have had a look at the stripe connect link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide but it doesn't seem to provide a guidance for react native. Or is there another platform similar to stripe that can provide this?

Comment: Stripe doesn't have a React Native library or official support at the moment unfortunately so there's no direct guide.

Comment: Thanks. What about tipsi-stripe? Can that be used to build a marketplace? Thanks

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid!

Comment: I was having a lot of problems with tipsi-stripe there was a bit of a workaround to get Android to work, but iOS builds kept failing. You could try signing up for the beta version of official Stripe React Native package https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/b1a1053eaac7496eb0ae7892ebd68973 it took only a couple of days to get approved.

Comment: Stripe now has an official RN SDK, https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native, but it's mostly just for payments. Connect account creation can happen in a webview, or  manually via server-side APIs